# Time duration (moment)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am writing a simple script which would output duration of time from specific time. I am using `moment` and `moment-duration-format` library

```
var timeStart = moment('2017-01-29T12:00:00Z'),
timeNow = moment();

var timeDuration = function(timeStart, timeNow) {
    return moment.duration(timeStart.unix - timeNow.unix()).format('H:m');
};

console.log(timeDuration(timeStart, timeNow));
```

Can somebody help me out with this? I don't know do I need to work with unix or iso or something else. And don't know if I need to subtract time or not.

Comment: Help you out with *what*? What issue(s) are you running into?

Comment: One thing that jumps out is that you're using `timeStart.unix` in one place but `timeNow.unix()` (note the `()`) in another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want the return to look like this:

```
return moment.duration((timeNow.unix() - timeStart.unix()) * 1000 ).format('h:mm:ss');
```

unix time is in seconds and duration wants ms.